# Drawing a PDF full of formatted text with images on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf

Is it possible to create a page with formatted text that is stored in core data. The text would need to be displayed with paragraphs and a few images. I have already written the code to create a PDF with one line of text, but I am unsure of the pattern needed to layout the PDF in a nice document way. One of reasons is I had to write the code in C. The data that will be in the document is of course In core data. And I do not know what the best practice is for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a particular need for PDF, the best practice is to use HTML and UIWebView. WebView is the primary formatted-text displayer for iPhone. iPhoneOS 3.2 added CoreText, which is another option if you have serious layout needs, but it generally isn't needed for simple formatted text and data.

The [Text and Web Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW1) includes a good discussion of your formatting and layout options. Generally UIWebView is still your best bet.

Comment: is it possible, once the UIWebView is styled and formatted, to create a PDF out of that View and email it to the user?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a method on iPhone. On Mac, it's NSView -dataWithPDFInsideRect:. Trying to capture the rendered view into PDF data is likely to be frustrating. If your real goal is a PDF rather than formatted text, then you may need to build it up by hand. The layout routines you likely want are in NSString(UIStringDrawing). Search for sizeWithFont: and you'll find the page. Actually working out where each paragraph goes is your issue. If complicated, you should read up on Core Text, CTTypesetter, etc. If simple, draw it a paragraph at a time with the UIStringDrawing methods.

Comment: Rob thank u for sharing I will investigate. I am also looking into the possibility of writing HTML but need to know if I can embed cocoa messages in-between the HTML tags. I do know I can create nsstrings that have HTML tags in them, but I would really like to layout a normal HTML page.

Comment: Generally I have addressed this by laying out the HTML in a static Resource file and substituting tags in it. For instance, I would search for %NAME% and replace it with my data.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure NSData (your c bytes) could be stored in NSManagedObject.
Even if not. Why don't store only metadata in CoreData? Is much more simpler for example: info needed to render the page wanted, etc.
I am not sure archiving the hole PDF in CoreData is a good approach.